# Special UUID primary key for laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a users table that doesn't use an auto increment primary key, instead it uses a binary uuid primary key. I set up my custom model to interact with my table however, I'm having trouble trying to find records by using `::find()` because for a case like this, this uuid needs to searched by using `HEX()` and `UNHEX()` mysql functions. How to I override this and have whatever is in `::find()` to be hexed. The name of the model is Player.

So if I was to try to find a user with a uuid of `9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef`, I cannot find them by doing:

`Player::find('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef')` since the uuid needs to be unhexed.

I've tried `Player::find("UNHEX('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef')");` with no results.

Here's my model so far:

```
class Player extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'players';
    protected $connection = 'game';
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

    public $incrementing = false;    
    public $timestamps = false;


}
```

The datatype for uuid is binary(16)

---

**Update**

I've got it to work by using `Player::find(DB::raw("UNHEX('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef')"));` however this is a lot to write every time I need to look up a user.

Is there any way I can have the parameter for `::find()` always run through `DB::raw("UNHEX('uuid')")` or be passed through the function `hex2bin()`?

I am 100% certain I will always be using UUID so I want to override `::find()`, not create a new method.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you show me how to go about implementing 'uuid' as primary key in laravel 5. I'm having some trouble doing the same. I've articulated my problems in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817067/laravel-5-using-a-uuid-as-primary-key

Comment: Use [my traits on github](https://github.com/alsofronie/eloquent-uuid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to unhex it in PHP prior to passing it to mysql:

```
Player::find(hex2bin('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef'));
```

You could add this method to your `Player` class:

```
public static function findUUID($uuid) {

    return self::find(hex2bin($uuid));

}
```

Now any where in your project you can call it like:

```
$result = Player::findUUID('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef');
```

If you do not want to declare it statically you can:

```
public function findUUID($uuid) {

    return self::find(hex2bin($uuid));

}
```

and then reference it in your code with:

```
$result = new Player;
$result->findUUID('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef');
```

Comment: Why not just create your own find() method in your model?  I would avoid using whereRaw since you lose all the benefits of Eloquent when you use it.

Comment: I'm very new to the eloquent ORM, I'm now trying it out. Can you provide an example for me?

Comment: Yes, this is using the find() Eloquent method, so it will behave the same. I just updated the post to show you to do it without a static declaration.

Comment: Man, someone must really hate all these answers. Thanks this worked, it must be static because making a new instance of the model means I'm creating a new row.

Comment: Calling a new instance of the class will not insert a new row into the database unless you are using the save() method at the end.  It is simply creating a new object and is completely safe :)

Answer (score 2):

This should allow you to override the native find() behavior and not have to use findUUID() instead:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

public static function find($uuid)
{
    return parent::find(hex2bin($uuid));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want it like that, you can also do `Player::find('9d823b9eec224cbea10b69bec2c5adef')` with this

```
class Player extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'players';
protected $connection = 'game';
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

public $incrementing = false;    
public $timestamps = false;

public static function find($uuid, $columns = array('*')) {
    return self::find("UNHEX('$uuid')", $columns);
}

}
```

**EDITED**

added self, as user Elliot Fehr suggested

Comment: "Declaration of Player::find() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::find($id, $columns = Array)"

Comment: Added $columns parameter as an array, now I have "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"

Comment: I should have mentioned all the things I've tried already. I've already tried all this and got these errors.

Comment: If I can't do it, I'll just stick to manually using UNHEX in ::find