# Using a UUID as primary key with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to create tables that will have a primary key which is a UUID defined as `binary(16)` instead of the default auto-incrementing `id` field.

I've managed to create migrations using raw SQL statements though `DB::statement` like so:

```
DB::statement("CREATE TABLE `binary_primary_keys` (
                      `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
                      `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                      `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                      PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
                  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;");
```

However, I have trouble getting the model working. I've followed the tutorial available [here](http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/using-uuids-laravel-eloquent-orm/). I've defined my model like so:

```
class UuidModel extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $primaryKey = 'uuid';

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        /**
         * Attach to the 'creating' Model Event to provide a UUID
         * for the `id` field (provided by $model->getKeyName())
         */
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string)$model->generateNewId();
            echo($model->{$model->getKeyName()});
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get a new version 4 (random) UUID.
     */
    public function generateNewId()
    {
        return Uuid::generate();
    }
}
```

where `Uuid` is an alias to `Webpatser\Uuid`.

One problem, I'm having is I cannot derive `UuidModel` from `Eloquent` as explained in the tutorial. In fact I don't see an `Eloquent` class. I'm deriving from `Model` instead. I am guessing the tutorial was written in Laravel 4.

I would appreciate help in implementing tables with UUIDs as primary keys in Laravel 5.

**EDIT 1:**
So, if I define my class like so:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent
class UuidModel extends Eloquent { ... }
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent' not found in /home/vagrant/transactly/app/UuidModel.php on line 8
```

If I remove the `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` line, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Eloquent' not found in /home/vagrant/transactly/app/UuidModel.php on line 8
```

**Edit 2:**
I have discovered that the `static::creating` event is never called for when instances of `UuidModel` are created.

I tried setting up the `creating` event listener in `AppServiceProvider` but that's not being called as well. Interestingly, the `creating` event is not called for a regular Laravel generated model `User` either.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    /**
     * Attach to the 'creating' Model Event to provide a UUID
     * for the `id` field (provided by $model->getKeyName())
     */
    echo "Booting...\n";
    UuidModel::creating(function ($model) {
        echo "Creating Uuid Model...\n";
        $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string)$model->generateNewId();
    });

    User::creating(function($user){
        echo "Creating User Model...";
        $user->name = 'Forced Name in boot()';
    });
}
public function register(){}

}
```

Comment: Did you try id with char(36)?

Comment: No I didn't. I'd imagine that char(36) would be less efficient.

Comment: I really don't know, but i think that compare binaries does not had the same precision in comparison and if you use, you should convert to binary, right? This article can be helpful http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/

Comment: I think, at the bit level, a binary(16) is just a number, only four times larger than a regular int(4). Integer comparisons will always be faster than char(36) comparisons. The article you point out to proves char comparisons are slow. If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say the author is seeing the slowdown because he's using a char(36) column as pk instead of binary(16).

Comment: So you're saying that you get an error that the `Eloquent` class is not found? If so, please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @Bogdan I've adding the error messages in **Edit 1**

Comment: The full namespace for the use statement should be `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`. And you can then have `class UuidModel extends Model { ... }`.

Comment: @Bogdan if i'm not wrong laravel 5 has a EventServiceProvider to handle events http://laravel.com/docs/master/events

Comment: @LeonardoJorge Laravel does have an EventServiceProvider in which you can register events, but that's not a required place to put them.

Comment: @CodePoet You're probably misunderstanding when the `creating` event gets triggered. It gets triggered before a newly created model is about to be saved to the database, not when you create a new instance of the class such as `new UuidModel()`. And in fact that's logical because if you'd want to generate any UUIDs that's the correct time to do it. You can read more about this in the [Eloquent Events Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events).

Comment: @Bogdan the creating event https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1666

Comment: @Bogdan But i believe that using this approach you probably will need to create a listener to which model that extends UuidModel

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

Comment: @Bogdan I understand that `creating` event is called just before saving to the database. I made sure I called `save()` on the new `UuidModel` instance. The `creating` was never triggered. It wasn't triggered for the standard `User` model either.

Comment: @Bogdan I've seen the Eloquent Events Documentation. That's where I got the idea to catch the events in the `AppServiceProvider`. I'm sure I'm missing something because even the `Users:creating` event is not firing or perhaps it's firing but not being caught. And that's laravel's standard auto-generated model without any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I got the thing working like a charm (not tested unit testing):

1. `class UuidModel extends Eloquent` is an older (Laravel 4) construct. We use `class UuidModel extends Model` in Laravel 5
2. The solution was to move the

   ```
   UuidModel::creating(function ($model) {
       echo "Creating Uuid Model...\n";
       $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string)$model->generateNewId();
   });
   ```

   from `AppServiceProvider::boot()` to `EventServiceProvider::boot()`. No other changes were required. Everything worked as expected.

I still don't know why (2) works in `EventServiceProvider` and not in `AppServiceProvider` as explained in the official [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events). But judging from the name, that's perhaps the way it was meant to be.

Comment: I would use a trait rather than create a “UUID model” class that extends the base `Model` class. That way, you can add and remove the UUID functionality without having to change the class it extends. Also, I don’t know why you used raw SQL in your migrations?

Comment: @MartinBean Yes, now that I've got it working, I will try traits. Thanks for the tip. I'm using raw sql, because AFAIK, SchemaBuilder does not support binary columns. My UUID columns are binary(16) for maximum efficiency.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations: under the sub-heading “Available Column Types” you can find binary.

Comment: @MartinBean I saw that, but that's mapping to the BLOB type without a specified length. Not entirely sure if BLOBs will be as efficient as BINARY(16) which are essentially number 4 times bigger than an INT. I believe MySQL doesn't store BLOB values in the same table.

Comment: I made a simple trait to use in order to make a model use uuid instead of auto increment. You can find it at https://github.com/alsofronie/eloquent-uuid . It's made as simple as possible because testing a lot of options will slow down a process already slow :).

Answer (score 4):

How about this idea for storing a 36chr UUID as Binary(16) :

IMO there is an ***advantage in not having Laravel generating the UUID***.  Namely, if new records (some day in the future) get inserted into the database from outside the application the UUID field is properly populated.

#### My suggestion: Create a UUID default value trigger using migrations

(this trigger makes the DataBase server do the work to generate the UUID  each time a new customer is inserted)

```
<?php namespace MegaBank\HighInterestLoans\Updates;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MigrationTriggerForCustomers extends Migration
{
public function up()
    {
    
        DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_customers
                      BEFORE INSERT ON    
                    `megabank_highinterestloans_customers` 
                      FOR EACH ROW
                      SET new.uuid = UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), "-","");');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER `before_insert_customers`');
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want to get a human-readable version of your UUID just do the following:

```
SELECT HEX(UUID) FROM customers;
```

Anyway, hope this helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution without using events.

UUidModel.php

```
<?php        namespace App;

    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

    class UuidModel extends Model

    {

    /**

    * Insert the given attributes and set the ID on the model.

    *

    * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query

    * @param  array  $attributes

    * @return void

    */

        protected function insertAndSetId(Builder $query, $attributes)

        {
            $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
            $id = $attributes[$keyName] = $this->generateNewId();
            $query->insert($attributes);
            $this->setAttribute($keyName, $id);
        }

    /**
    * Get a new version 4 (random) UUID.
    */
        public function generateNewId()
        {
            return 'uuid!!' ;// just for test
        }
    }
?>
```

Model Example Car.php

```
<?php namespace App;

    class Car extends UuidModel {
    }
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but the `insertAndSetId` function in never called. Actually, I can see in the base class's implementation that `insertAndSetId` is only called when `$this->incrementing` is `true`. In my case, since the `uuid` column is not incrementing, I've set `$this->incrementing` to `false`.

Comment: using this way the incrementing attribute must be true (default), just look at Car model

Answer (score -3):

also try use this package will automatically generate and assign UUID field in your model, also can show and update by UUIDs key.

https://github.com/EmadAdly/laravel-uuid